# Перекрытие состояний во внешней системе

Tags: архитектура, проектирование, xorg, xlib

Как часть проекта, необходимо написать обертку над оконным менеджером, которая реализует интерфейс `WindowManager`. Для каждой операционной системы, свой класс. На данный момент работаю с linux, а именно с `xlib`.

В `WindowManager` имеются методы позволяющие задать видимость, состояние окна (скрыт, скрыт в трей, свернут), развернутость по ширине/высоте/обоим направлениям, а также полноэкранный режим и отображение границ окна.

Однако, как оказалось, например, если сначала свернуть окно, затем скрыть (`setVisible(false)`), а затем показать (`setVisible(true)`), то оно появится как будто и не было свернуто (будет развернутым, обыкновенным окном). Хотя теоретически, на другой платформе (Windows например), эти методы могут быть реализованы так, что после тех же действий, окно появится, но будет свернутым.

Тут и возникает проблема: я не могу гарантировать одинаковое отображение окна **везде**, при перекрытии состояний (например, одновременно полноэкранный режим и свернутость в трей). Нет никаких гарантий, что на разных платформах, в таком состоянии окно будет отображаться одинаково.

*К тому же может быть так, что на какой либо платформе, ее метод, например, включения фуллскрина, может **автоматически** выключать невидимость окна, а где-то может и оставлять это на плечах программиста. Это тоже проблема.*

Решения:

1. Написать в документации: перекрытие состояний является платформенно-зависимым.
2. Реализовать надстройку, над системой состояний `xlib`. Что я имею ввиду: в классе `WindowManagerXXX`, добавить много флаговых переменных которые будут выражать состояние окна по мнению обертки. Также необходимо при изменении состояния конечным пользователем (максимизация, сворачивание) ловить эти события и соответствующим образом изменять внутреннее (логическое, если позволите) состояние. А при изменении кого-либо состояния вызывать метод вроде `restoreState()`, который проанализирует ожидаемое состояние и в соответствии со стратегией **выбранной мной** установит нужное отображение для окна (возможно проигнорировав некоторые состояния, т.к. они несовместимы (например скрыт и полноэкранный режим), но я смогу это контролировать).

Самое интересное, что подобная проблема, относиться не только к `xlib`, а к любой используемой внешней системе.

Итак, вопрос в общей форме: каким образом решить проблему представления системы при перекрытии состояний которые могут быть несовместимы, а могут быть и совместимы на разных платформах? И надо ли ее вообще решать, ведь это, в некотором смысле, паранойя. Придется для любой библиотеки, для которой не документировано поведение для перекрытых состояний, писать что-то странное и страшное.

**TL;DR**

Иначе говоря, что делать если не имеется стандарта, указывающего как будет отображаться окно если включено два несовместимых (теоретически) состояния? Нужно писать собственную надстройку над этим? (Вопрос не только об окнах)

P.S. Не предлагайте, пожалуйста, использовать `toolkit`'ы, проблема не в этом.